# CSV files and OLEDB in VB.net - Exception with no info

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv, oledb

I'm trying to parse a user-submitted csv file in ASP.NET with VB.  Here is my function:

```
Public Function getData() As DataSet
        Dim conn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path.GetTempPath() + ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"""

        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(conn)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + sourceFile, cn)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

        cn.Open()

        Dim dt As New DataSet()

        da.Fill(dt)

        cn.Close()
        Return dt
    End Function
```

the error I get is:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled by user code
```

ErrorCode=-2147467259
  Message=IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
       at SuperSMITH.CSVReader.getData() in C:\Projects\Allied\App_Code\CSVReader.vb:line 29
       at tools_Step2.uplFile_FileUploadComplete(Object sender, FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e) in C:\Projects\Allied\tools\Step2.aspx.vb:line 58
       at DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.ASPxUploadControl.OnFileUploadComplete(FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
       at DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.ASPxUploadControl.RaiseFileUploadComplete(UploadedFile uploadedFile, String& errorText, String& callbackData)
       at DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.ASPxUploadControl.Validate()
  InnerException:

The error comes up at the `da.fill(dt)` line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Every search result that comes up says it has to do using reserved keywords in the CSV file or in the `SELECT` statement. What's the value of `sourceFile`?

Comment: It's "C:\Documents and Settings\greg\Local Settings\Temp\tmpF61.tmp"

Comment: I should add it's from an upload form.  I think I need to go another direction with this, use some other kind of adapter.